# string operation in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a below string array object which has 4 elements. I want to compare the elements of this list to an string and want to check if string is part of this list.

```
list = ["starter_v2", "professional_q", "custom_v", "basic_t9"]
 str = "starter"
if list.include?str #should return true but returning false as it is checking the full string not the substring
```

Above if condition should return true, however it is returning false.

Can someone suggest me how to fix this, as I am new to ruby and want to compare strings.

For my usecase, in list object I will always have entries with `"_"` followed by an alphabetic character and I will compare this by string without `"_"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enumerable#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F) checks if a given value matches any value in the given enumerable. A substring is not equivalent to a string that contains it, so this check fails.

Instead, you want to check if any string in the array matches your substring. Ruby has handy facilities for this: [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) lets you iterate an enumerable, yielding each element to a block, and then will return true if any invocation of the block returns true.

So, you can use:

```rb
list.any? {|element| element.include?(str) }
```

What this will do is check each entry in `list` to see if `str` is included in it; once a match is found, it'll stop iterating and return true. If it goes through the entire list without finding a match, it'll return false.

You could also use use `element.start_with?` if you know that your search string should always match the first part of the string, or you could use a more complex condition which splits each element on underscore and compares the first part, or you could use a regex. The important part is that the block returns true when you want to indicate a match.